# How to POST a value from a button in Facebook's React render() to a Playframework Scala method

Tags: reactjs

I defined a route like this:

```
POST    /showBeerDetails:id    controllers.Application.showBeerDetails(id: Int)
```

Additionally, I have a Scala method:

```
def showBeerDetails(id: Int) = Action {
    Ok(views.html.showAllBeerDetails(id))
}
```

Now I have troubles to write the code for a button created by a React render() method that POSTs an ID that is received by the Scala method:

```
render: function() {
    var id = 42
    return <div><input ...></input></div>
}
```

How to post the 42?

(BTW, is it possible to use Play's template tags in the render method? JSX didn't compile the my code in all my tries.)

Answer (score 1):

You'd use the same POST from plain html: with the `form` action + method attributes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Of course, that takes you to another page and all.

Alternatively, you can use any AJAX library (jQuery, Superagent, etc.) you want and simply hook up a callback on the button's `onClick` or the `form`'s `onSubmit`. The point is, it's really just vanilla js. Call the ajax method in that callback.

Putting server-side template tags in your `render` is super weird. Technically, you should be able to, if your template produces valid jsx (aka, the jsx you'd write normally, `<input />` and all. Notice the self-closing `/`). I wouldn't recommend it.